# Circle & Triangle

Tags: functions

Take a point $P(a,e^{-a})$ where $a>-1$ on the curve $C:y=e^{-x}$. Let $S(a)$ be the area of the triangle surrounded by the tangent to $C$ at $P$, $x$-axis and $y$-axis.

Find the function $S(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent to a function $f$ at the point $(a,f(a))$ is given by $y = f'(x)(x-a) + f(a)$. In your case, it is quite easy to find. 
Then, you just have to find the intersection points of the tangents and the axes. You now have the three vertices that make your triangle. This triangle is of course a right triangle, and finding its area is easy : pretend it's a rectangle, find the area and divide it by 2.